# How to transfer value from a thread to the main program without blocking it?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

if you have see my precedent question, you have see that i was working on client/server system. I'm working on a multiplayer game. For receving message from the i use a thread for not blocking the main program where the video side work(ursina).

The problem is that i need to receve the new positions of the players who i receve on the thread in the main program for update it. I see things like queue or pipes but they always block the program(the update function). So, how do i do to transfer value from a thread to the main program without blocking it?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: *"if you have see my precedent question"* - we haven't, you should include the relevant code in your question. That is, a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can poll the queue to see if it has new values. Or you can use the timeout parameter at a place where you would sleep anyway, e.g. if you run with a fixed frame rate, you may sleep until it is time to render the next one. A timeout of zero also works like polling.

```py
inputs = queue.Queue()
try:
    key = inputs.get(block=False)
except Queue.Empty:
    pass
else:
    process(key)
```

Comment: thanks you for your respond. I wasn't aware of the fact that there is a timeout for get in queue. Have a good day.

Comment: @Druide Glad it helped, please don't forget to mark my response as an appropriate answer.